# Mysql with where condition and between dates with inner join

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have the following query which works fine, but I want to add `between` dates, which I cannot get to work.

This is working:

```
SELECT
user.user_id,
user.s_name,
user.f_name,
user.year,
it_club.date,
it_club.room,
it_club.period,
it_club.id,

COUNT( it_club.user_id ) as uvisits

FROM it_club
INNER JOIN user ON user.user_id = it_club.user_id
WHERE it_club.room = '$room'
GROUP BY it_club.user_id
ORDER BY `uvisits` ASC";
```

I want to add this:

```
AND
it_club.date
BETWEEN '$start'
AND '$end'
```

I have tried the following but it doesn’t work.

```
...

FROM it_club
INNER JOIN user ON user.user_id = it_club.user_id
WHERE it_club.room = '$room'
AND 
it_club.date   
BETWEEN '$start'
AND '$end'
GROUP BY it_club.user_id
ORDER BY `uvisits` ASC";
```

The `$room`, `$start` and `$end` have values from jquery, which are working.

Any idea how to solve? I also would like to add a `where` to `it_club.period` in the same query.

What the query is doing is asking for all users in `IT1(it_club.room)` between 2013-09-21 and 2013-09-26 from 2 tables, `user` and `it_club`.

I would also like to add the period of the day(`it_club.period`) into the query at some point.

This would read as all users in `IT1(it_club.room)` at Lunch(`it_club.period`) between 2013-09-21 and 2013-09-26.

Comment: doesn't work how? no results? syntax error?

Comment: Can you share the error message please?

Comment: Can you output the sql statement that you are sending to db?